# legend colors are not matching seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using sns.pointplot and since there is no `label` attribute I've decided to create my custom legend but my problem is that the colors do not match.

my dataframe looks like this:

```
                  deploy    deployed_today_rent total_rent  cum_deploy  hourly percent  cum_percent
10min                       
2019-10-01 05:30:00 6           0   0   6   0.000000    0.000000
2019-10-01 05:40:00 0           0   0   6   0.000000    0.000000
2019-10-01 05:50:00 6           0   0   12  0.000000    0.000000
2019-10-01 06:00:00 13          0   0   25  0.000000    0.000000
2019-10-01 06:10:00 0           0   0   25  0.000000    0.000000
2019-10-01 06:20:00 0           1   1   25  0.040000    0.040000
2019-10-01 06:30:00 0           0   0   25  0.000000    0.040000
2019-10-01 06:40:00 0           1   1   25  0.040000    0.080000
2019-10-01 06:50:00 1           1   1   26  0.038462    0.118462

fig,(ax1)= plt.subplots(nrows=1)
fig.set_size_inches(22,17)

sns.pointplot(data=test, x=test.index, y="total_rent", ax=ax1,color="blue", label="total")
sns.pointplot(data=test, x=test.index, y="deployed_today_rent", ax=ax1, color="green", label="deployed_rent")
sns.pointplot(data=test, x=test.index, y="cum_deploy", ax=ax1, color="#BEC647", label="cum_deploy")

ax1.legend(labels=["total", "deployed_rent", "cum_deploy"], fontsize=15)

plt.savefig("test.png", dpi=300, bbox_inches="tight");
```

It successfully creates a legend however colors in the legend does not match the lines.

[image]

Comment: Can you include screenshots and/or the data you used to plot with so I can test your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists), you can do this by creating a ‘proxy artist’ for each line using `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` like so

```py
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

a = Line2D([], [], color='blue', label='total')
b = Line2D([], [], color='green', label='deployed_rent')
c = Line2D([], [], color='#BEC647', label='cum_deploy')
plt.legend(handles=[a, b, c])
```

Which should produce a legend with three different color lines of default width with their respective labels.